# iOS: cancel delete event UITAbleViewDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to know the delegate method that gets called when the user cancel the delete operation of the UITableViewCell. Now to answer the potential question that "Why do I need this?", following is the scenario:

I have a table view where the item is displayed (which is left aligned to the main view) in a UILabel and its price is displayed in a separate UILabel (which is right aligned to the main view).
Now once the user presses the red (kind of no entry) button to delete any item, the whole cell is indented to the left and half of the price is clipped because of being out of the view. This looks quite ugly and hence I hide the price label upon press of this 'pre-delete' button (which works fine). But I want to display the price tag back when the user dismiss the delete button without deleting the cell. but I am unable to find the cancelDelete kind of event for tableview cell.

Thanx :-)

Comment: Hi, to cancel delete what your user need to do ? Push the button again ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might work instead, it stops the tableview from indenting the cells while editing:
Set UITableView's shouldIndentWhileEditing property to NO.
Implement the delegate-method tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Or you can do this when you create your cells:

```
cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
```

Hopefully this works for you.